# Tensor Networks with Julia and implementing given Hamiltonian

Tags: hamiltonian, density-operator, software, ground-state, tensor-network

I have this Hamiltonian: (ref: https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5843)

[image]

I want to solve this Hamiltonian by using tensor networks. I wanted to make the implementation with ITensors, Julia. However, I am having difficulties with writing this into the desired format.
given here: https://itensor.github.io/ITensors.jl/stable/tutorials/DMRG.html

Yet, more importantly, Julia-ITensors lib gives an error as this Hamiltonian is not Hermitian. Is there any suggestion for me to solve this type of hamiltonians?

Any help will be appreciated. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ITensor library asks to write the Hamiltonian in Hermitian form. You have to obtain the analytical Hamiltonian correctly first to solve the error.

As for the question of another lib, I know [TenPy](https://tenpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), it doesn't require you the write Hamiltonian in Hermitian form.